# Getting Parameter already exists for @StartDate error in a new report with no existing parameters

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I'm getting an error stating that the parameter @StartDate already exists when creating a new data set using the following Script:

```
DECLARE
        @Domain VARCHAR(50) --pulled from user login in report
      , @StartDate DATE   --date report is to start, report is hardcoded for 7 days
      , @LoginStatus VARCHAR(50);

SELECT  userName
    , datetime
    , appDomain
    , message
    , CASE
        WHEN message LIKE '%succeeded.%' THEN 'Succesful'
        WHEN message LIKE '%No Perms%' THEN 'Unsuccesful'
      END AS 'LoginStatus'
FROM table
WHERE (CONVERT(DATE, dateTime) >= @StartDate AND CONVERT(DATE, dateTime) <= DATEADD(dd, 7, @StartDate))
      AND table.appDomain = @Domain
```

The @Domain will use the user's login to limit returns to just their login, eventually I will create a drop-down for @LoginStatus for the 2 variables in the case statement. The problem is when attempting to create a new dataset in a new report I keep getting the error for @StartDate. The only thing I can think for the error is the where statement limiting the time frame to 7 days. How can I get around this error and still be able to limit to the 7 day time frame using the user input @StartDate
?

Answer (score 0):

For any parameters that are passed in from the report, you should not declare them in the dataset query.

Typically you would declare them whilst testing in SSMS or whatever tool you use, then comment them out in the dataset query.

So to fix this, just remove the declarations for any values that will be passed in from the report.

You must make sure that the parameter name in the report is identical (case sensitive) to the variable used in the dataset query. e.g. SSRS parameter name = `StartDate` and therefore the t-sql variable must be called `@StartDate`

Comment: So in this case, since I have Domain and StartDate in the query I should remove them both from the declaration statement leaving just the LoginStatus variable? (couldn't leave the (at) sign in the comment)

Comment: That's correct. It's seems a bit odd but SSRS injects the parameter value(s) into the query so there is no need to declare them.